# SQL Server Query Store - why does it not always use the forced plan?

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2019, query-store

I forced a plan to be used for a specific query ID.  However, SQL Server seems to only use the forced plan occasionally, interspersed with other plans.  See image below.  I forced plan 154315 for query ID 146019 and usage of this plan is indicated by the black check mark.  Why is it not always used?

[image]

UPDATE:  Well, nevermind.  Just learned about [morally equivalent plans](https://www.littlekendra.com/2018/03/12/what-is-a-morally-equivalent-execution-plan-and-why-is-it-good/).

Answer (score 0):

It seems the success of forcing the plan is not guaranteed. The [sp_query_store_force_plan](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/system-stored-procedures/sp-query-store-force-plan-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15) says:

> When a plan is forced for a particular query, every time SQL Server
> encounters the query, it tries to force the plan in the Query
> Optimizer. If plan forcing fails, an Extended Event is fired and the
> Query Optimizer is instructed to optimize in the normal way.

I recommend you see [Query Store Fundamentals: Why my plan forcing has failed?](https://dbanuggets.com/2021/12/27/query-store-fundamentals-why-my-plan-forcing-has-failed/). Here's some of the article content:

Query for latest failure reason:

```
Code Source: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/performance/best-practice-with-the-query-store?view=sql-server-ver15
USE [QueryStoreDB];
GO

SELECT p.plan_id, p.query_id, q.object_id as containing_object_id,
    force_failure_count, last_force_failure_reason_desc
FROM sys.query_store_plan AS p
JOIN sys.query_store_query AS q on p.query_id = q.query_id
WHERE is_forced_plan = 1;
```

That article also mentions the following XE Session to capture the history of failure reasons:

```
CREATE EVENT SESSION [Querystoreforcedplanfailures] ON SERVER 

ADD EVENT qds.query_store_plan_forcing_failed
ADD TARGET package0.event_file(SET filename=N'C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\MSSQL15.MSSQLSERVER\MSSQL\Backup\qserror.xel'),
ADD TARGET package0.ring_buffer
WITH (STARTUP_STATE=OFF)
GO
```

Comment: Thanks Ronaldo, but this plan is not failing.  force_failure_count is 0.  I edited my OP to indicate that I think this has to do with "morally equivalent plans" which is explained by Kendra Little here:  https://www.littlekendra.com/2018/03/12/what-is-a-morally-equivalent-execution-plan-and-why-is-it-good/

Comment: @camaro322hp, I see. I thought **not using** the plan was equivalent to **a failure**. Thanks for clarifying!